# Why was "When to use struct ..." deleted on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

There *was* a question on SO: [When to use struct in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c/). Why was it deleted? As [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124282/142742) concerning the rep fixes asks, *why put all that effort into answers only to have it deleted?*

Some disconcerting issues about deleting:

- Question with high visibility do not have any weight on decisions to delete
- Questions with significant upvotes carry no weight
- Good (read high quality) answers obviously have no bearing on the decision to delete
- Deletion of the questions produces orphan objects/references

In particular, deletion of this question left me with a badge for which no one can see **why** I have it:
[image: Date received Populist badge]

I understand that clean-up happens and I am thrilled that rep recalcs are a thing of the past. I am more upset over the deletion of the question and loss of a lot of work by myself and others who had input. Why wouldn't some questions be rolled/merged rather than deleted. Especially when there are so many 'struct' questions on SO that are closed?

It simply is not fair to delete (apparently without any regard) questions and throw away the efforts of those who answered. I know I was not the only one to lose out on this particular deletion. I (and those who upvoted) felt that the answer provided credible information that is now gone.

Comment: I think mods need to stop force-closing or force-deleting questions that are clearly judgement calls.  This has been happening *a lot* lately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the mod who deleted this question was tricked by the opening line of the question:

> ***Here's a fun one***. When should you use struct and not class in C#? [emphasis mine]

I think this is a legitimate question about the C# language, whose chief answer is backed by facts and references to Microsoft.

I vote that we re-instate this question.

Comment: I'd support restoring it, the question could use some cleanup ("Do you agree?", ick) but the top answer is quite good.

Comment: @Kevin - yeah, the OP had a lot of junk in his question—smiley faces, banter, etc.  But overall I think it adds value to the site.

Comment: I've had a stab at some cleanup - does that work better now?

Comment: Appreciate the efforts! I think they'll have to force a recalc for rep, though ...lawlz

Comment: @IAbstract - my by click of the mouse you just broke 4K  :-D

Comment: Now ...should I post a bug reporting that the "recalc fix" is not taking into account posts that have been reinstated?

Comment: @IAbstract - yeah, I would.  Nick and company will likely want to know

Comment: @AdamRackis: looks like it finally added the rep back ...awesome.